# Is there a way to get the task manager id of the flink taskmanagers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to get the integral id / hash id of task manager and report metrics using that.

Comment: Try Flink WebUI RESTful API: **/taskmanagers**, it will return a list of running TaskManagers with their instance ID.

Comment: i want to get it programmatically, via code / some api

Comment: Ah, I see. You can use RpcService.connect() to get a **JobMasterGateway**, which provides a RPC method, **requestRegisteredTaskManagers** to retrieve all registered TaskManagers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by getting YARN application container ID for each task manager was running into.

The container id's suits my purpose, thanks for all your insights though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the metric system for that.

Within a (rich) user-defined function call getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().getAllVariables().get("<tm_id>")

Comment: This gives me the taskId, i.e. if multiple tasks are deployed on the same node i'll get different parallelism id for those tasks and not global taskmanager_id (for the jvm)

Comment: Did you try it out? Because the task id is accessible with "<task_id>".

Comment: yup but the task id is a random hash, i need predictable numbers e.g. 1, 2, 3.....

Comment: Flink does not have logical IDs for tasks or Taskmanagers; these just don't exist when the job is executed. For a task the closest thing to that would be the task name, which can be set through the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a *JSON* formatted output of the scheduled TaskManagers by:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8081/taskmanagers/"
```

If you are interested only in the id of the TaskManager, you can fetch it using *jq* (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Example of fetching the id of the first TaskManager:

```
local task_manager_id=`curl -s "http://localhost:8081/taskmanagers/" | jq -r '.taskmanagers[0].id'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check which tasks are mapped to which task slot on the JobManager’s web frontend at http://localhost:8081. You have also a bunch of metrics.

Comment: I'm looking to access this from withing the code itself, also i need to publish my own app specific metrics.